# Chrome Extension - Execute code when Chrome Starts

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, getjson

I'm working on a Chrome Extension, and I'm researching how to execute code when chrome starts.

I have these files:

```
script.js
index.html
manifest.json
```

And in script.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"NameOfStreamer",function(c) {
        if (c.stream == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to execute this code not when the HTML is done rendering but when Chrome starts in the first place, then rerun every minute.

It would be the same idea as `$(document).ready()`, but executed when Chrome starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please start by reading the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It's not a long text, but extremely important.

A popup only exists as long as it is open; there is no code to run when it's not.

A [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) is the solution: it's an invisible page that is created as soon as Chrome starts and continues running throughout the lifetime of Chrome.

---

Implementation:

In your manifest, declare your background scripts (in the order of loading):

```
"background" : {
  "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
},
```

The code will be run as soon as Chrome starts. No `$(document).ready` wrapper needed:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"NameOfStreamer", function(c) {
  /* ... */
});
```

If you need it repeated, you can use [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) or simply [DOM intervals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
getData();
setInterval(getData, 60000); // Once every minute

function getData() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"NameOfStreamer", function(c) {
    /* ... */
  });
}
```

---

That solves the problem of getting the updated data. But the background page is invisible. If you want to show the data, you can use the browserAction popup.

This way, you separate your extension into the part that handles the data (background) and a popup that displays it.

You will have to request the data from the background somehow; how to do this is too broad for this question, but you can use [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or directly access the background page with [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage). You could also store the data in [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), accessible from the popup. This is probably not an exhaustive list.

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you might want to look into [notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Comment: That's a good explanation , thank you so much Xan. So if i understand , in my jquery.js i do nothing for the moment =) ?

Comment: "Your" jquery.js? Since you're using jQuery, you should include a copy of it in your extension.

Comment: I assume that `script.js` is included in your popup. I gave you an idea of what you should put there in the last part of my answer.

Comment: Yes i remove my commentary because a found the error =) but thank you =)

Comment: But when i launch the extensions , in the console i have this "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on this line "$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"ogaminglol",function(c)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onCreated` event of chromium:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

**[Docs for event onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated)**

Comment: Yes. The answer is extremely unhelpful, as putting this code in existing files will do exactly nothing. OP needs an explanation of the concept of a background page vs popup. But even then it will _not_ fire when Chrome opens the first time - it will be registered too late. So, it's a wrong answer.

Comment: Hmmm . ok Xan , i understand what you say , perhaps you have a tutorial to explain me the concept of background page vs popup =) ?

Comment: @BenoitRastier I'm writing an answer.